# Python - replace letters in a string only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need to figure out how I can replace letters in python only once.

example:

```
s = "a b c d b"

# change letter 'a' to "bye" and letter 'b' to "hay"
# .replace function is problematic because:

s = s.replace('a', "bye")
print(s)

# will print to "bye b c d b" now if I try to replace letter b 
# it will replace the first b of "bye" aswell thats not what I want
# output I want: "bye hay c d hay"
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your question title is misleading: You don't want to restrict the number of replacements, but a replacement on word basis.

Comment: suggestion to what I should change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know of a character that is not present in your original string, the easiest way (requiring no additional packages) would be to replace all characters to those 'temp' characters, and then replace those temp characters. For example:

```py
s = 'a b c d b'

s = s.replace('a', '\0').replace('b', '\1') # Put temporary characters
s = s.replace('\0', 'bye').replace('\1', 'hay') # Replace temporary characters
```

Comment: That can certainly work on a case-by-case basis, but you'd have to copy and paste more and more of those lines any time you want to add changes, and it breaks as soon as you're unlucky and pick a temp code already present in your string.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Sure.. but if OP wants a very simple solution to their problem that doesn't require any additional packages or knowledge of regex, and they have a small subset of strings to replace (i.e. can guarantee no 'abnormal' characters) this does exactly that. And this can be made into a single line, if desired.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), as follows:

```
import re

s = "a b c d b"


def repl(e, lookup={"a": "bye", "b": "hay"}):
    return lookup.get(e.group(), e.group)


result = re.sub("[ab]", repl, s)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
bye hay c d hay
```

Quoting the documentation of `sub`:

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
> occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the
> pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a
> string or a function

Comment: What if the 'a' and 'b' I want to replace are defined at runtime lets say I have a list named repl_vars = ['a', 'b'] how would the code change?

Comment: @HaskellPlease if you have a similar list of mappings (I'll call `end_subs`), you can zip them into a dict with `lookup=dict(zip(repl_vars, end_subs))` - you would then need to change `'[ab']` to `'[' + ''.join(repl_vars) + ']'` (or some equivalent)

Answer (score -1):

I like Dani Mesejo's suggestion of using `re.sub`, but I find it easier to use when wrapped in a convenient function like so:

```py
import re

def multi_replace(text, changes):
    return re.sub(
        '|'.join(changes),
        lambda match: changes[match.group()],
        text
    )
    
text = 'a b c d b'
changes = {'a': 'bye', 'b': 'hay'}

text = multi_replace(text, changes)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
bye hay c d hay
```

You can simply call `multi_replace()` with any text and dictionary of changes as input, even ones generated dynamically, and it will happily return the updated text.